# Integrating a probability distribution, as a step to reach another distribution - I am not able to follow their step.

Tags: probability

I am reading a paper, and I am unable to follow.

> To produce a prior favoring sparse  solutions, we again assume
>   that $β_j$ arises from a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance
>   $τ_j$,
>
> $p(β_j|τ_j)=N(0,τ_j), j=1,...,d.$
>
> Further assume, a priori, that the $τ_j$’s arise from an
>   exponential distribution with density
>
> $p(τ_j|γ)=\frac{γ_j}{2}exp(−\frac{γ_j}{2}τ_j), γ>0$
>
> Integrating out $τ_j$ then gives an equivalent nonhierarchical
>   double-exponential (Laplace) distribution with density
>
> $p(β_j|λ_j)=\frac{λ_j}{2}exp(−λ_j|β_j|)$
>
> where $λ_j = \sqrt{γ_j} > 0$

How does integrating out $τ_j$ lead to their result?

I don't even understand what they mean, e.g. I thought first they integrated  to solve for $τ_j$ but that is obviously not correct: $\int{p(τ_j|λ)} = 1 = -(\frac{γ_j}{2})^2exp(−\frac{γ_j}{2}τ_j)$. Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all the $j$ subscripts, the authors are integrating out $\tau$ by calculating
$$
\int_{\tau=0}^\infty p(\beta\mid\tau)p(\tau\mid\gamma)\,d\tau,\tag1
$$
viewing the result as a function of $\beta$, with $\gamma$ a constant. Plugging everything in, we get
$$
\int_{\tau=0}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\tau}}\exp\left(-{\beta^2}/2\tau\right)\frac\gamma2\exp(-\gamma\tau/2)\,d\tau.\tag2
$$
Substitute $u=\sqrt{\gamma\tau}$ and the integral (2) is proportional to
$$
\int_{u=0}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac12\left({\gamma\beta^2\over u^2}+u^2\right)\right)\,du.
$$
Consult a table of definite integrals, or use Wolfram Alpha, to find that this last integral is proportional to
$e^{-\sqrt{\gamma\beta^2}}$, as claimed.